# How should I add a use case to an existing answered question?

Tags: discussion, answers, search, duplicate-questions, self-answer

I found the answer to my question in another, but the title of the question was specific enough that it made me consider posting and answered question for searchability. What's the recommendation here?

Specifics:

My question (ruby / Rails related):

> Why am I unable to rescue from RangeError when performing
>   ActiveModel#where with an out-of-range integer?

Answered question ([Unable to rescue from Redis connection refusal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657876/unable-to-rescue-from-redis-connection-refusal)):

> Unable to rescue from Redis connection refusal

The answer in both of these cases is the same: delayed execution of the actual statement that was throwing the exception, so while console prodding implied a specific statement was throwing an exception, in context the exception would permeate outside of a rescue block.

I don't think this answer is sufficiently covered by the search terms "inability to rescue from exception", but as these two issues are of the same origin I wanted to somehow add more generalized search terms, or at least my own question, to this answer so that other searches would point to that answer.

I don't know of a good way to do this other than to post a new question and link to the original. Is there a more accepted way to do this?

Comment: Post a question, vote to close it as duplicate. Flag for attention if you want to jump the queue.